# Slimscroll not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, slimscroll

I am new to slimscroll. I am working on an angular page where slimscroll works fine but when I click on some link and go to other page scroll stops working even for the main page but when I refresh this page it works fine. 
Is there any thing I am missing which is making scrolling disable?
What is the thing which is enabling scroll on page refresh?

```
<div slimscroll data-height="455" scrolly condition="scrolling_condition">-->
                            <table class="table-grid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="item in project.list |
                                                        filter:project.search:strict |
                                                        startFrom: (project.pagination.current_page - 1) * project.pagination.items_per_page |
                                                        limitTo: project.pagination.items_per_page"
                                    data-ng-show="project.list.length > 0">
                                    <td width="13%">{{item.name}}</td>
                                    <td width="16%">{{item.portfolio.name}}</td>
                                    <td width="12%" data-ng-if="!project.isClient">{{item.client.name}}</td>
                                    <td width="7%" data-ng-if="!project.isClient">{{item.status}}</td>
                                    <td width="12%">{{item.installation_type}}</td>
                                    <td width="7%">{{item.dc_rating}}</td>
                                    <td width="12%">{{item.location.city_state}}</td>
                                    <td width="8%">{{item.location.country}}</td>
                                    <td width="13%" class="text-center">
                                        <a data-ng-href="#/entity/projects/view/{{item.id}}" class="action-link">
                                            <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg-icn"></i>
                                            <span data-ng-if='$last' infinite-scroll-disabled='max_data_loaded' infinite-scroll="project.loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance='1' ></span>
                                        </a>

                                        <a data-ng-href="#/entity/projects/edit/{{item.id}}" class="action-link">
                                            <i class="fa-lg-icn rg-pen"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="action-link" confirmed-click="project.delete({{item.id}})" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete this Project?">
                                            <i class="fa-lg-icn rg-bin"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr data-ng-show="project.requests.list == project.request_state.LOADING">
                                    <td colspan="6"><div class="main-loading">&nbsp;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr data-ng-show="project.requests.list == project.request_state.ERROR">
                                    <td colspan="6">
                                        <div class="error-loading-img"></div>
                                        <div class="error-loading-msg text-center">{{errorMsg}} <a href="#" data-ng-click="project.loadProjects()">Click here to reload.</a></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr data-ng-show="project.requests.list == project.request_state.SUCCESS && ((project.list | filter:project.search:strict).length == 0 || project.list.length == 0)">
                                    <td colspan="6">No records found.</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

If i scroll inside this div and click on any url inside it then on new page scrolling stops.

Comment: please provide some code, or code pen.

Comment: @KaranKumar is this code helpful?